# Device drivers and Interrupt service routines

Tags: assembly, x86, device, drivers

A very basic question. I have learnt that device drivers and interrupt service routines are some program or codes only. whenever required they are made to execute. 
Execution means CPU is executing some instructions out of its instruction set ISA. So does it mean that device drivers and ISRs are also machine instructions to generate the required result?

what exactly such programs likes device driver and interrupt routines made up of? do such programs also have a data segment, code segment and stack segment?

I am learning x86 assembly language and C .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an accurate assessment. A complex enough device driver has a data segment, code segment and a stack segment.

Comment: A computer runs from one routine to another routine to another or back to old routine, always, from the time it is turned on till the time it is turned off. Is it also true?

Comment: @Saurabh: In general yes. At the edge case your main application can be an HLT command in a loop. Then actual execution would happen only when processing hardware interrupt requests.

Comment: o.k. fine.. so routine, driver, procedure, subroutine are just fancy names for a block of instructions (only from the ISA), which on execution yields a desired result. there is nothing special about them as such except their different results.. Am I right in saying so?

Comment: @Saurabh: A complex enough driver contains a number of procedures/subroutines. You can compare it to a regular application. A GUI application calls a number of its procedures based on the user input via, say, GUI. A driver calls a number of its procedures based on the hardware interrupt requests.

Comment: Got that.. But is it true that any driver/subroutine can't do anything beyond the underlying ISA ? I am trying to get the bigger picture on this subject first. for any x86 microprocessor, all executables have the same structure - data,code, stack segment, no matter the code is what I compile in C language or a device driver program or any interrupt service routines. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Consider how to get data from a device. There are two ways:

- Polling: *Are we there yet? Are we there yet?* A program, OS kernel, device driver, whatever... keeps asking the device whether it has any new data.
- Interrupts: The device tells the CPU that it has something important, and *interrupts* the CPU. The CPU executes a routine called an Interrupt Service Routine to service the request, and then continues with whatever it was doing before it was interrupted.

Depending on your OS (or no-OS, just bare metal) a device driver can be a program, or it can be an integral part of your OS kernel, ...

A typical device driver will do several things: identifying devices, initializing devices, handling interrupts from the device, handling requests to write/read/configure the device, ...

Of course, modern CPUs tend to provide protection features, and don't allow arbitrary processes access to devices. So the device driver will either run at a high privilege level, normally as a part of the OS kernel, or in the case if userspace device-drivers it will use some well-defined interfaces provided by the kernel.

Comment: thanks a lot.. Out of curosity, what language is used to write such device drivers and ISRs ? assembly, C or some other language? Am  I correct to say that these drivers and ISRs are executable in themeselves? do they have extensions like .exe or .com or some new extensions?

Comment: It depends on the OS. On Linux, they are usually written in C, and compiled into an object file with `.ko` extension (kernel module) which gets linked into the kernel at runtime. Or they maybe statically linked to the kernel. OTOH, userspace drivers are normal programs which are run with enough privileges to access I/O ports or special device files.